# Getting local variables from a stack frame on the JVM

Tags: java, jvm, clojure, snapshot, locals

Is there any way to get a map or other data structure of the local variables in the current scope in on the JVM without using a debugger? That is, to get the locals of the current stack frame?

I know that there are stacktrace objects, but `StackTraceElement` has no way to get access to any state. It just tells you what method was called where, but not what was in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable names can be included in class files to aid debuggers, but `javac` doesn't do it by default. It requires the `-g:vars` option.

If it's present, a program could use a byte-code engineering library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to access the local variable names and scope.

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable) is poorly phrased, I think it is a duplicate, and its answers may be relevant to your problem. I would add that if you don't care about the names, the local variable type and scope are always included in each method's attribute table.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this. The compiler is always free to optimise away local variables, and providing such a method would prevent the compiler from taking advantage of this type of optimisation. When compiling a method, the compiler wouldn't be able to tell whether you called a hypothetical `getLocalVariables()` somewhere else in the program, so it would have to always put all declared local variables in such a map.

Comment: The local variables are available in a map in the StackFrame. You can have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html