# Method parameter values via introspection?

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

How/am I able, using introspection or reflection get the parameters a method 1 level up in the call stack and it's values ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359044/getting-local-variables-from-a-stack-frame-on-the-jvm

Comment: Linked question does not discuss parameter values, I think both questions could be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only through the [debugging interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/), not from within the Java code.

Why do you want to do that anyway? As part of productive code, it would violate all kinds of design principles.

Comment: Or my case: injection of logging code for gathering performance statistics in format method+arguments:performance.

Comment: @setec: That's exactly what AOP is meant for; doesn't even require calling a "logging method" from the method to be benchmarked, which I suppose is what you're trying to do.