# Howto get the java compiler to insert a variable name into a string

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I often find myself writing code like this:

```
throwExceptionWhenEmpty(fileType, "fileType");
throwExceptionWhenEmpty(channel, "channel");
throwExceptionWhenEmpty(url, "url");
```

The `throwExceptionWhenEmpty` method does something like this:

```
private void throwExceptionWhenEmpty(final String var, final String varName) {
    if (var == null || var.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Parameter " + varName + " may not be null or empty.");
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid this obvious redundancy passing the variable name as string. Is there a way the java compiler can insert the variable name in the string for me?

I'd be happy if I could write something like this:

```
throwExceptionWhenEmpty(fileType, nameOf(fileType));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Java cannot do this until it starts supporting closures which make fields (and methods) first class citizens of the programming language.

See http://docs.google.com/Doc?id=ddhp95vd_6hg3qhc for an overview on one of the proposals, in which you could do what you want using `#field` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

That should answer your question: [SO: How to get name of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable).

It's not (easily) possible in Java.

You could use a preprocessor and integrate it in your build process. That would probably be very simple and portable. But as  Stephen C said in the comments section, that's really not the Java way and is therefore not recommended.

Comment: -1 - don't recommend a preprocessors for this kind of thing.  It is not the Java way.  (I wouldn't even abuse the preprocessor to do this kind of stuff in C!!)

Comment: you are absolutely right, I added that to my answer. I didn't delete the preprocessor-statement since it'd would solve his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are lost when the code is compiled so unless Reflection provides access to them (and even then) I'm pretty sure it's impossible. Sorry.

Comment: This is why I asked for compiler substitution.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. Well I don't think any well known compiler can do it, but maybe a code preprocessor? Of course, they're often nastier than the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't really have a way to do this but you can get some help from your IDE (if you are using one). In Eclipse you can create a template like this that could help:

```
throwExceptionWhenEmpty(${varname}, "${varname}");
${cursor}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like (I might be misunderstanding what you want to do)

var.getClass().getName()

Where Var is your Object passed into the method as an Object.