# Getting variables from a method

Tags: java, variables, reflection

i use java reflections to get methods used in a class.I also want to get the variables name and their types used in those methods.How can i do that?Help

Comment: This question is a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have their names through reflection, (but you don't really need them anyway, names are just in the source code to make it more usable through the API).

To get the parameters, you'll have to use [`getParameterTypes`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes())