# Java. Instance variable length

Tags: java, exception, variables

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does Java have a limit on the class name length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039029/does-java-have-a-limit-on-the-class-name-length)
>   [Max name length of variable or method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695951/max-name-length-of-variable-or-method-in-java)
>   [Java.Variable name length.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359700/java-variable-name-length)

i stupid, i know, sorry...

i created this question [Java.Variable name length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359700/java-variable-name-length),
but here very bad example...
so, i try create new question,
i have this class:

```
class Test
{
int i=10;

public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println(new Test());
}}
```

where variable name is not 'i' but 'iiiiiii....' with length 65535 chars(iiiiiiiiii...)

.class file have the same size that .java file.
Compile - success.

but, when i>65535chars - `Exception: UTF8 representation for string "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii..." is too long for the constant pool`

bingo!

What conclusion can we do?

unlimited-length -  not 100% correct.

But i find some information that its problem not java language - its some problems with classfile, so somebody know: Whose problem?

Comment: I think he meant, that the variable name is not 'i' but 'iiiiiii....' with length 65535 chars.

Comment: So what is the question? Why do you think that the length of variable names is unlimited?

Comment: because, i read docs: An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that this question has been asked at least a couple of times ("*[Max name length of variable or method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695951/max-name-length-of-variable-or-method-in-java)*", "*[Does Java have a limit on the class name length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039029/does-java-have-a-limit-on-the-class-name-length)*").

The best answer seems to be that while the Java Language Specification does not place a limit on constant, class or variable names, the Java Virtual Machine Specification (specifically, the classfile format) imposes a limit of 65535 characters.  See [section 4.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659) of the JVM Specification, last bullet item.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. We can't name variables with more than 65534 chars. But who cares?

Comment: Well, sure, *you* can use comments, but *my* code documents itself... and everything else.

Comment: @Reese Moore, you need more than 65535 chars per variable name?

Comment: Sarcasm, it was a joke about how long 'self documenting' code can be sometimes (at which point it is less intelligible than if a good old comment were used).

Comment: @Reese Moore, Oh.. I see. In this case, it's good one)