# How to create a function that take a parameter and print its name?

Tags: kotlin, printing

```
val a = 5
println("a $a") // instead of this, we can call foo(a)
```

Calling `println("a $a")` many times is suffer. Can we create a new function and just call `foo(a)`?

Comment: @deHaar oh sorry, that's my bad!!!

Comment: @deHaar I want to create a new function `fun foo(a: Any)` that print it's argument name and value. Like `foo(a)` will print `a 5`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way in Java to find the name of the variable that was passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984550/is-there-a-way-in-java-to-find-the-name-of-the-variable-that-was-passed-to-a-fun)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easily / directly possible (at the moment)...

Consider your `fun`, you would have to do it with the following syntax:

```kotlin
fun foo(a: Any) {
    println("'${::a.name}' : $a") // doesn't compile
}
```

Unfortunately, this feature is currently only available for properties and function names, but not for local variables (yet), according to [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/nameof-to-get-names-of-program-elements/1518/10) and according to the most recent Kotlin Eclipse Plugin, because it shows me

[image]

Read the mentioned discussion and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188226/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable-in-kotlin) in order to find possible alternatives and more information in general.

Comment: Even if it were possible, it wouldn't help in this case; I assume that for the call `val x = 3; foo(x)` the asker wants to print `x : 3`, but using `::a.name` would print `a : 3`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, you are right... This is not a very good example of what is not working. I don't know if any reflection might work...