# Getting name and type of local variables from a Java program

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode

This is the code which I am trying out:

```
JavaCompiler compilerA = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int resultA = compilerA.run(null,null,null,"/Users/a/Documents/Java/a.java");
System.out.println("Compile result code = " + resultA);
File fileA = new File("/Users/a/Documents/Java/a.class");

JavaCompiler compilerB = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int resultB = compilerB.run(null,null,null,"/Users/a/Documents/Java/b.java");
System.out.println("Compile result code = " + resultB);
File fileB = new File("/Users/a/Documents/Java/b.class");
```

Here I am compiling a Java class and then using reflection to get all the function names, parameters and return types. However, I have no clue how to get the names and return types of the local variables of the functions. I tried looking up bytecode outline but it says it isn't available for netbeans. Please help me out.

Comment: You can't get the names of local variables with Java reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Comment: I know i cant get them using Java reflection. But cant I get them using some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [javac compiler options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). Especially -g:vars.

This fills the local variable table for debuggers.

See same qustion [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)