# Take name of variable as input and output its value - Java

Tags: java, variables

I need to make a method that takes the name of a variable as its input, searches the class, and outputs the value pointed to by that variable. However, as you might have guessed, I am having problems with it:

```
public String myMethod(String varname) {
    return varname;
}
```

As you can see, all the above does is return the input string. Is there any way to get it to do otherwise?

Edit: for those requesting an explanation, here it is:

Suppose I have the following code:

`String foo = "foo";
String bar = "bar";`

I want to make a method that takes the name of a variable and returns its value. So, if I used the above method and wrote `myMethod(foo)`, the output would be "foo"; similarly, I want `myMethod(bar)` to give "bar".

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want to pass by reference ? Your question is ununderstandable ...

Comment: A possible duplicate [how to get the name of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: I feel I understand what you mean, but you should provide a better example - maybe just in pseudo code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Java **Reflection** API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html). For example:

```
private String foo = "foo text";
private String bar = "some text";

public String myMethod(String varname) throws Exception {
  Class<?> c = this.getClass();
  Field field = c.getDeclaredField(varname);
  Object fieldValue = field.get(this);
  return fieldValue.toString();
}

// myMethod("foo") returns "foo text"
// myMethod("bar") returns "some text"
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/AQFEY)**.

#### References:

- [The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/TOC.html)
- [Getting and Setting Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

Comment: How would I get that to work if I wanted to define the name of a class as well as the name of a variable? So if I wrote `myMethod(someClass, someVariable)`, I would receive the value of `someClass.someVariable`.

Comment: Hang on a second - would this work for the above:

`String path = someClass + "." + someVariable;`

`String s = myMethod(path)`

Comment: @Bluefire: No, It's a bit more complicated. But I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Say, for example, you have two instances of the class `Foo`, if you pass the className `Foo`, which of those instances would you choose? Also, it's probably better for you to open a new question for this.