# Android Junit test local final variables

Tags: android, junit

I have this code in my MyClass.java :
variable 'C' is the one added.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               final MyLocalClass mlc = new MyLocalClass(A, B, C);
          }
}
```

and I want to do Junit test like this:
get the instance of 'mlc' then get the "C" in 'mlc' and compare.

```
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    Field field = MyClass.class
            .getDeclaredField("mlc");
    field5.setAccessible(true);
    final MyLocalClassinstance = (MyLocalClass) field5
            .get(activity );
```

But error from OS:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldExceptio
```

Could I get the instance of a local final variable?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable .

Comment: Thank you Yam Marcovic. Is there a way to get the top activity thread and get the value from that thread? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot as explained by @Yam Marcovic.

but you can easiliy change the code to make it testable:

I would make `mlc` local to the Activity instead of local to the anonymous OnClickListener handling class like this

```
public class MyActivity : Activity {
    public MyLocalClass mlc; 
    public void Init() {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       mlc = new MyLocalClass(A, B, C);
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

this can be easily tested

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();   
// assert on activity.mlc.C
```

Comment: Thank you k3b, but I'm just responsible to the Junit test and there is no way to change the source. Anyway thank you.