# Is there a way I can make sure that an object created by using my class gets the name that the user assigns to it in java

Tags: java

I build a class with the constructor:

```
public Door(String name){

  this.name = name;
 }
```

Is there a way where I can create a default constructor where the name becomes whatever the user assigns this object. For example:

```
{

  Door blackDoor = new Door();
}
```

Would make the

blackDoor.name = blackDoor?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Unless... No, forget it.

Comment: The obvious question is: why would you need this?

Comment: This is possible through reflection, but only while debugging. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459674/how-to-get-variable-name-in-java) for example. **Don't use this in production builds. Names can change and variables might be removed due to compiler optimizations.**

Comment: @GiantTree thanks a lot. I was just curious to know if it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bleh {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlackDoor bd = new BlackDoor();
        System.out.println(bd.name);
    }
}

class Door {
    String name;
    public Door(){
        this.name = this.getClass().getName();
    }
}


class BlackDoor extends Door{
}
```