# How can i get the name of a property by its value?

Tags: java, reflection, field

I have a class:

```
public class Something{
    public static final int SOMETHING_0 = 0;
    public static final int SOMETHING_1 = 1;
    public static final int SOMETHING_2 = 2;
    // ... etc
}
```

values are unique, How can i get the name of a property by its value?

via reflection, for example:

```
// intValue = 1
String getNameByValue(int intValue){
    ...
    // returns "SOMETHING_1"
    return nameOfProperty;
}
```

Comment: what happens if there is more than one property with `intValue` of 1?

Comment: You may consider using Enumeration for such a case.

Comment: This might get you going in the correct direction if you have to use reflection : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112590/get-the-class-instance-variables-and-print-their-values-using-reflection

Comment: Berger is right, you probably shouldn't be using class constants for this, and definitely not reflection.

Comment: Can you describe the more general aim of what you're trying to do? You might find that people are able to help you better. @Berger's suggestion of an Enumeration is probably what you want.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave i just want to print the choosen option in a switch(intChoosen) I'm ussing constants to choose an option and i want to print: `selected: SOMETHING_1` instead of `selected: 1`

Comment: there are two ways, you could do some nasty tricks with reflection, or implement them as enum

Comment: I cant change to Enums because its a remote service where the only value sent is an int value i cant change type of parameter sent to Enum.

Comment: You can get an enum constant based on its ordinal (which is an int), and then display the enum's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this in hard way:

```
 public class Something {
        public static final int SOMETHING_0 = 0;
        public static final int SOMETHING_1 = 1;
        public static final int SOMETHING_2 = 2;

    }

 String getNameByValue(int intValue) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : Something.class.getFields()) {
        if (field.getInt(null) == intValue) {
            return field.getName();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

and if you do this, Santa will go postal and slaughter dozen of innocent kittens.

Our you could do this in correct way an implement your values as enum

```
public enum Something {
        SOMETHING_0(0),
        SOMETHING_1(1),
        SOMETHING_2(2);
        final int val;
        Something(int val){
            this.val = val;
        }
        static public  Something byNumber(int number){
            for (Something somthing : Something.values()){
                if (number==somthing.val){
                    return somthing;
                }
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Value not found");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll take correct way, thank you very much.

Comment: @Kuriel good, remember always try to save kittens:) Other thing which is worth to remember, enums are very useful tool, so do not afraid of using them.

Comment: I updated my code, everything is working as i wanted, thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is this:

```java
public class Something {
    public static final int SOMETHING_0 = 0;
    public static final int SOMETHING_1 = 1;
    public static final int SOMETHING_2 = 2;
    public String toString(int value) {
        switch (value) {
            case SOMETHING_0: return "SOMETHING_0";
            case SOMETHING_1: return "SOMETHING_1";
            case SOMETHING_2: return "SOMETHING_2";
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value: " + value);
    }
}
```

```java
// Use:
int value = Something.SOMETHING_1;
String name = Something.toString(value);
```

If `int` values are consecutive, starting at `0`, then you can use an `enum` and it's `ordinal()` position:

```java
public enum Something {
    SOMETHING_0, SOMETHING_1, SOMETHING_2
}
```

```java
// Use:
int value = Something.SOMETHING_1.ordinal();
String name = Something.values()[value].name(); // or toString()
```

If `int` values are *not* consecutive, you can still use `enum`:

```java
enum Something {
    SOMETHING_0(0),
    SOMETHING_10(10),
    SOMETHING_20(20);
    private final int value;
    private Something(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public static Something from(int value) {
        for (Something something : values())
            if (something.value == value)
                return something;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value: " + value);
    }
}
```

```java
// Use:
int value = Something.SOMETHING_10.getValue();
String name = Something.from(value).name(); // or toString()
```

Alternatively, if you want display text to be different from constant name, and you don't like exceptions, you can do this:

```
enum Something {
    SOMETHING_0 ( 0, "Something 0"),
    SOMETHING_10(10, "Something 10"),
    SOMETHING_20(20, "Something 20");
    private final int    value;
    private final String description;
    private Something(int value, String description) {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public static Optional<Something> from(int value) {
        for (Something something : values())
            if (something.value == value)
                return Optional.of(something);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    public static String toString(int value) {
        for (Something something : values())
            if (something.value == value)
                return something.description;
        return "Unknown value (" + value + ")";
    }
}
```

```java
// Use:
String desc = Something.toString(value);
// Or:
String desc = Something.from(value).map(Something::getDescription).orElse("Oops");
```

Comment: @Kuriel Does the new 4th version fit you?