# How can you initialize a superclass's variable in its subclass so that the subclass has its own value to that variable unique to the other subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance

For example, if in the class 'animal' there was the String variable 'species,' and I made a subclass 'Cat,' how could I initialize the species variable so that for cat, it contained the value "cat"? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: [java initialize base class fields in subclass constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845169/java-initialize-base-class-fields-in-subclass-constructor) Or just enter the following in the search box at the top of this Web page: ___[java] initialize superclass member in subclass___

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java initialize base class fields in subclass constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845169/java-initialize-base-class-fields-in-subclass-constructor)

Comment: Don't use `static` for your fields. Static is class-level, not instance-level. Use the constructor to pass values. In any case, you should provide a [mre] with the code you have now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that shows that you can have a superclass that has a general field (in our case species) and that field can be instantiated in the subclasses of the superclass with different values. The subclass can have a default constructor that sets a default value for the general field (in our case the species has the default value of cat) and we can have constructors that help us set a new spice for the subclass Cat.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Cat tiger = new Cat("tiger");
        Cat jaguar = new Cat("jaguar");

        System.out.println("Animal specie: " + animal.species);
        System.out.println("Normal cat specie: " + cat.species);
        System.out.println("Tiger cat specie: " + tiger.species);
        System.out.println("Jaguar cat specie: " + jaguar.species);
    }
}

class Animal {
    String species;

    public Animal() {
        species = "animal";
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        species = "cat";
    }

    public Cat(String specie) {
        species = specie;
    }
}
```

[Here you can see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XlpD.png)