# How to add variables to list if there is many variables?

Tags: java

I am learning JAVA. If I want to add some variables on list. What I know how is like this:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
String c = "c";

List<String> verifyItem = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);
```

How about if I have many variables. For example, from a to z, do I need to manually add it like that?

```
List<String> verifyItem = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d, ..., y, z);
```

Because I declared 100+ variables and need to add them on list. Do we have other approaches to add them smarter? Any hotkey in Eclipse or Intellij?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I hardly think so. But wouldn't it be smarter to just create these variables in the list in the first place?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't declare 100 variables, you could've used a collection. Now to add all of them to the list, you can iterate over the original collection and add them to the list.

Comment: Are the variables incremental? As in the example in you have given, is there a pattern to the variables, as you may be able to create them directly to the list in a loop

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112590/get-the-class-instance-variables-and-print-their-values-using-reflection

Comment: but please don't use it ^

Comment: Do you need the variables or only the list?

Comment: You should adhere to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names start with lowercase. I've edited the code in your post for you.

Comment: If you have 100 variables like that, it is probably not a good design. Can you tell us *why* you need 100+ variables?

Comment: Thanks for you guys. Actually there are ~20 variables only. The variables are fields in registration form like firstname,lastname,nationalid,mobile number, address.....etc around 20 fields. I am using selenium with framework for automation testing. That framework can get data from excel sheet. So I need to declare variables like          String firstName=excel.getdata("firstname");   20times. And then put them to list so I can write a loop to check all 20 fields are displayed correctly in web page.

Comment: Why don't you save directly to map in key value pair, instead of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because I declared 100+variables and need to add them on list.Do we have other approach to add them smarter? Any hotkey in Eclipse or Intellij?

I don't think declaring 100+ variable inside the code is a good idea. In the future, another coder who read the code will be confused with this 100 variable.

If I were you, I will create a separate file to store the 100+ variables value. Then, I'll create a function to read them.

```
//Let say you have file called variable.txt

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("variable.txt"));

try {
    String line = br.readLine();
    List<String> verifyItem = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (line != null) {
        verifyItem.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}

//do something with verifyItem
```

**Note**: you can also change `List<String> verifyItem` into `HashMap<String, String> verifyItem` if you would like to access it easily.

It's up to you. It depends on the way you use `verifyItem`.

I hope this answer will help you.