# How can I sort variable values, and then print them in order, largest to smallest?

Tags: java, variables, sorting

I would like to sort my list of variables, from largest to smallest, and then print out the names of the variables. I have already tried Arrays, but when printing the array out, it prints out the value of the variables, not the names.

Comment: Codes are thousand times more effective than 100 hundred words. Please post your code too.

Comment: @RohitJain this case is very simple: *print out the names of the variables*. This isn't possible.

Comment: You can at least have a field on your *variables* that states its name and use it when printing the sorted array, but there's no way you can now the name of a variable at run time.

Comment: Hi user2811760 - perhaps you could help us by giving an example of your input and expected output, and code you've tried. Even more helpful, explain your reasoning!

Answer (score 6):

Printing out variable *names* lies somewhere between extremely tricky (on the order of hunting through `.class` files and hoping for the best) and [downright impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable). If I were you, I'd use a `Map` instead, where you can map variable values to their "names" in the code, and then you can sort the keys and print the values in order.

---

The problems with accessing variable names are outlined well in the answers to the question I linked, but the basic issue is this: what if I have an object with no name defined for it? What if there's more than one name for a single object?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, You can't print the names of stack variables in java, as that data does not exist in runtime.
You can wrap your variables in a class and override its toString() method.
For Example, instead of

```
int x = 3;
```

use:
    public class Wrapper {
    private final int value;
    private final String name;

```
public Wrapper(int value, String name) {
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
}

Wrapper x = new Wrapper(3, "x");
```