# Selenium WebElement Logical name implementation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Wanted to ask if anyone is aware about any implementation or pattern for Selenium WebElement interface to get "Logical Name" of any given WebElement object in Java.

I am looking for something like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//tr[2]/td[@class='listrow1'][3]")
    private WebElement txtProvider;
    txtProvider.SetLogicalName = "Provider TextBox" 

assertEqualsSoft(txtProvider.getText(), hashMap.get(EMHashMapConst.PROVIDER), txtProvider.getLogicalName + strMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something similar through Reflection.

[Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

(edit: Before the revision of the question it wasn't totally clear that this was related to Selenium API property, I thought you were just looking for way of programatically ID'ing variable. If so, reflection is good to look into, as it is a generic programming practice.)