# How to get the field name of a variable?

Tags: java, oop

I've got some `final static Road`'s declared like so:

```
public static final Road street = new Road().setWidth(20).setRoadColour(0xAAAAAA).setRoadLengths(500, 100).setDiversity(0);
public static final Road junction = new Road().setWidth(60).setRoadColour(0x999999).setCustomGenerator(new JunctionGenerator());
public static final Road normalRoad = new Road().setWidth(30).setRoadColour(0x999999).setRoadLengths(1000, 2000).setDiversity(2).setChanceForTurn(0).setRoadChance(street, 1);
public static final Road motorway = new Road().setWidth(60).setRoadColour(0x0000FF).setRoadLengths(1000, 100000).setDiversity(1).setChanceForTurn(0).setRoadChance(normalRoad, 1);
```

And i want to be able to fetch the name of the road by it's instance, e.g-

I was thinking the method would be something along these lines

```
Road.street.getClass().fieldName();
```

And that will return the name of the field I declared it with.

Comment: Use either enum or inheritance

Comment: You believe the Roads would work better as Enums? I'll give that shot. It didn't occur to me at first.

Comment: If you have only four types with very similiar properties, just differencing by numbers, then yeah

Comment: Can you still use factory methods with Enums?

Comment: You can have public static factory methods in an enum, or do you mean something else? Also, enums have constructors like any other classes and can even override methods!

Comment: Why don't you add setName()/getName() methods to the Road class? The name of the variable should not matter.

Comment: That's what I shall do. see @Alexander's answer

Answer (score 3):

Give your `Road`-class a `private String roadname` and a getter, it would be the the conventional way to do it.

Comment: This was my initial idea, I just thought I'd see if there was a way to get ahold of the fieldName. This will have to suffice for now however. Thanks.

Comment: I agree. According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable), getting a the variable name of a class instance is impossible in Java.

Comment: Jet a conventional OO-application should not have to use reflection in my opinion.

Comment: You can get the names of variables in a given instance (or static) through reflection, but you would have to program your own way to translate a *reference* to a variable into that name.  Putting the name in the class is at least 20 times easier.