# How to use name of parameter inside a declared path for a file - java

Tags: java, csv

I have a method called createCSV where I convert a List into a csv file. I want to use a pathname for the new file with the name of the List, which I give as a param. How can i do this? Here is my code:

```
public static File createCSV(List<String[]> custList) {

    String methodName = "createCSV";
    String csv = "/home/oracle/outputcsv/" + custList + ".csv"; // pathname
                                                                // with
                                                                // listname.csv
    File file = new File(csv);

    try {
        custList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        FileWriter filewr = new FileWriter(file);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(filewr);

        custList.add(0, new String[] { "customerId" });

        for (String[] list : custList) {

            custList.add(0, new String[] { "customerId" });

        }

        writer.writeAll(custList);
        logger.debug("[{}] custlist = {}", methodName, custList);

        logger.debug("[{}]CSV written successfully", methodName);
        writer.close();

        logger.debug("[{}]The file is supposed to be :) : {} ", methodName,
                file);
        // return file;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.debug("[{}] IOException {}", methodName, e);
    }

    return file;

}
```

I also have a problem in displaying all my list elements. I tried to use a for statement but it didn't help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean that you do something like List<String[]> foo = null; createCSV(foo); and then you want to write it as foo.csv?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, Rhand. can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re asking for is not possible in Java. The parameter names are not retained; because what name would you give an argument of `1`, or `new Object()`?

However, simply add a second parameter to your method:

```
public static File createCSV(List<String[]> custList, String filename) {
    …
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! Furthermore, can you tell me what am I doing wrong in the parsing of the List? Because only one parameter is written, yet i have more in the List.

Answer (score 2):

custlist is your list and you want a String to concatenate to your csv path. Add the list name as a parameter to your method.

```
createCSV(List<String[]> custList, String yourListName)
```

then

```
String csv = "/home/oracle/outputcsv/" + yourListName + ".csv";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution presented by [Veronica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987685/veronica) and [Bombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43582/bombe).
If you are unwilling to type in the parameter name, you could try to recover it using techniques discussed here: [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744226/1014666)