# Getting the name of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, get, jframe, jlabel

I have a label in my JFrame. It's variable name is `l_1001`.

I want to get this variable name in output. How can I do it?

I tried

`System.out.print(l_1001.getName())`

But output rotates `null`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Yes indeed.. I wasn't referring reflection..

Answer (score 2):

See the docs, [`JLabel#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29):

> Gets the name of the component.

In Java, you cannot simply return the name of the variable (without using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)), you should set it before, you can use [`JLabel#setName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) to do that.