# Java get variable name as string

Tags: java

```
final static int 
    DRAGON = 5,
    SNAKE = 6;

String this_item = "DRAGON";
int item_value = super_func(this_item);//must be 5
```

Is it possible to implement this `super_func`, as shown above?

Or maybe I am asking for too much?

**EDIT:**

I am not allowed to use enum. I can:

a) use a map (as someone pointed, or 2 array lists) or
b) do this with some pro way (but it doesn't seem possible).

Comment: Is this just an idle question? Why do you need to do this? Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do that lead you to need this.

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Comment: @timgeb That is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's technically possible to do this using reflection, I'd **strongly** recommend you to rethink your structure, and consider one of the alternatives that have been mentioned in the other answers.

The simplest would probably be to use a map

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class VariableNameTest
{
    private static final Map<String,Integer> map;
    static
    {
        Map<String, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();        
        m.put("DRAGON",5);
        m.put("SNAKE",6);
        map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getValue("DRAGON"));
        System.out.println(getValue("SNAKE"));
        System.out.println(getValue("Boo!"));
    }

    public static int getValue(String name)
    {
        Integer i = map.get(name);
        if (i == null)
        {
            // Do some error handling here!
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

But if your intention is to extend this with additional functionality, you should probably introduce a class like it was recommended in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23846279/3182664

Just for completeness: The reflection solution, **not recommended!**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class VariableNameTest
{
    static final int DRAGON = 5;
    static final int SNAKE = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getValue("DRAGON"));
        System.out.println(getValue("SNAKE"));
        System.out.println(getValue("Boo!"));
    }

    private static int getValue(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> c = VariableNameTest.class;
            Field f = c.getDeclaredField(name);
            return f.getInt(null);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
        {
            // Many things
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            // may cause
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            // this to 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            // fail horribly 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not recommended, because it's too complex and there are simpler alternatives, right?

Comment: Not recommended, because `Many things` `may cause` `this to` `fail horribly` - and there are simpler, less invasive solutions, yes.

Comment: He said he's not allowed to use enums

Comment: @Cobbles This "edit" of the original question was done while (or shortly after?) I referred to ZouZou's recommendation. However, I intentionally said that he might introduce a *class* (which does not necessarily mean that this class should extend the `Enum` class). Such a class could offer a functionality that is *roughly* similar to that of an `enum`. Of course, one could not `switch` over the instances/values of this class, but a `valueOf(String)` method could be offered, solving the initial issue.

Comment: @Marco13 Ah I understand, sorry for accusing you :P

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what this value is supposed to represent, but you could use an [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
enum Animal {
    DRAGON(5),
    SNAKE(6);

    private final int a;

    private Animal(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

And then

```
String this_item = "DRAGON";
int item_value = Animal.valueOf(this_item).getA();//5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of a variable with *Java Reflection* tricks, but why not declaring a simple enum and using it:

```
    enum Creature{
    DRAGON(5), SNAKE(6);
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know such a thing is not possible, but you coudl store your variables in Map

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("DRAGON",5);
map.put("SNAKE",6);

int itemValue = map.get("DRAGON"); //Sets itemValue to 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a switch() statement.

```
int item_value;
switch(this_item) {
     case "DRAGON":
         item_value = 5;
         break;
     case "SNAKE":
         item_value = 6
         break;
```

or different solution doing the opposite

```
private String getAnimal(int itemValue) {
     switch(item_value) {
         case 5:
             return "DRAGON";
         case 6:
             return "SNAKE";
         default:
             return null;
}
```