# Instance name at runtime with the Scala Reflection API

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Lets start with the following example:

```
class Foo {
  override def toString = ???
}

val instanceName = new Foo()
println(instanceName) // Should print "instanceName"
```

Using the Scala Reflection API (or any other method), how can I get the name of the instance of a class at runtime ? How to get this information from the AST ?

Same question but for Java: [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the question doesn't really make sense.  I'll try to explain why.

Imagine that suitable magic existed that would allow toString to do as you wish.  Now let's add a few more lines:

```
class Foo {
  override def toString = ???
}

val instanceName = new Foo()
val larry = instanceName
val moe = larry
val curly = moe
println(instanceName.toString)
```

What would you expect to be printed -- instanceName?  larry?  moe?  curly?  All of those identifiers are bound to the same object.  When toString executes, the variable used to refer to the object is gone -- the object reference is in `this` and that's all there is.

An object knows nothing about which identifiers -- representing data on the stack or even in other objects -- refer to it.  Not only does the `toString` method not have access to the name of the variable, there really *isn't* a single variable for it to know about.