# print out object with handy way

Tags: java

I made a code using my `No2 class` but I'm confused about how to print out entire code without using array.

I just know one way to print out this code, I'm using `System.out.println()` 7 times.

Please help me to figure out another way/handy way to do it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         No2 a1 = new No2("1","A",3,6000);
         No2 a2 = new No2("2","B",4,8000);
         No2 a3 = new No2("3","C",1,1000);
         No2 a4 = new No2("4","D",2,4000);
         No2 a5 = new No2("5","E",5,10000);
         No2 a6 = new No2("6","F",2,4000);
         No2 a7 = new No2("7","G",3,6000);
   }
```

Comment: Why can't you use an array?

Comment: I just want to find another way to print out it, but yet to find another way

Comment: Are you against any sort of collection? Can you use an ArrayList? or a List? If you can't use a collection, then you won't get much better than the above.

Comment: I just don't  understand about ArrayList or List. whether we can use looping for print out code above ?

Comment: If you're willing to learn about them, beyonddc's answer is a good one.

Comment: Also, here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you are interested. Regardless of whether or not you use it here, Lists are a must-have skill in my opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<No2> no2List = new ArrayList<No2>();
        no2List.add(new No2("1","A",3,6000));
        no2List.add(new No2("2","B",4,8000));
        no2List.add(new No2("3","C",1,1000));
        no2List.add(new No2("4","D",2,4000));
        no2List.add(new No2("5","E",5,10000));
        no2List.add(new No2("6","F",2,4000));
        no2List.add(new No2("7","G",3,6000));

        for (final No2 no2 : no2List) {
            System.out.println(no2.toString());
        }
    }
```

You'll need to implement the toString() method in No2 class.
Also you'll need to import java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList in your main class.

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Is `final` required in the for loop? I've never seen it used there before.

Comment: Not required, just a habit.  You're just preventing a variable from being reassign to something else.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new, and for a good answer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `toString` method in your `No2` class to prettify your output. I'm totally guessing here:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "id: " + id + ", " +  
           "letter: " + letter + ", " +
           "number: " + number+ ", " +
           "bigNumber: " + bigNumber;
}
```

I'm afraid that, without using a `Collection`, your task is nearly impossible (and quite useless). You can tough use a single `println` for your objects:

```
System.out.println(a1.toString() + "\n" +
                   a2.toString() + "\n" +
                   a3.toString() + "\n" +
                   a4.toString() + "\n" +
                   a5.toString() + "\n" +
                   a6.toString() + "\n" +
                   a7.toString() + "\n");
```

which is [pretty ugly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron).

Answer (score -1):

You can implement toString method in your `No2` Class, then use an array to store your variables :

```
array[0] = new No2("1","A",3,6000);
// ...
// Then try this line of code
Arrays.toString(array);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Though this is the correct answer design-wise, he said specifically he doesn't want to use an array.

Comment: Oops I overlooked that, sorry.