# how to get name and value of each parametes in java method?

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to get the name of each parameter and value coming to my method in java. I searched about it but I could not find something to help me. Can you show me a solution.
I have a method as below

```
public HashMap<String, Object> putallinMap(Object...pars){
     HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     map.put(pars[0].{name}, pars[0].{value});
     return map;
}
```

This is How I call the method above.

```
String str1 = "Hello world!";
int myint = 55;
double myDouble = 11.5;
...// there can be other primitive types, long, short, Double etc.

HashMap<String, Object> map attrInMap = putallinMap(str1, myint, myDouble);
```

Sow What I expect to have a hasmap like below.

```
{"str1":"Hello world!", "myint" : 55, "myDouble": 11.5}
```

Comment: You can't get names but only values.

Comment: It depends. If your variables are declared at the class level, you can get their names. Otherwise, if they are local, I don't think it's possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the `variable name`, since its only a reference to a class.
I suggest you simply get the `Object Type` instead.
in term of getting the value just add the object

Something like this

```
public HashMap<String, Object> putallinMap(Object...pars){
     HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     map.put(pars[0].getClass(), pars[0]);
     return map;
}
```

and based on ur input the output will be as follows:

```
{"String":"Hello world!", "Integer" : 55, "Double": 11.5}
```

**NOTE** :

for further info I found this nice stackoverflow question:

[Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my requirement force me to have name of attribute instead of class name. I remember I have seen something like that in play framework source code. They were keeping request params to next scope by doing something like that. But ı could not find it now..

Comment: @gabby well I suppose that is a java problem, you are probably using a wrong programming language to achieve your task.

Comment: I can not get the play framework repo to my workspace now. When I do I will share from here. Im sure Im using Java :)

Comment: @gabby as far as I know, play uses scala also, maybe its some scala library that allows u to do it

Comment: Sorry not to tell version. what i checked last time was play 1.2.5