# How do I convert a string representation of an integer to a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm using a ContentResolver query to get some data from a database in Android. That's not the issue.

The method returns string representation of integers,

```
INT TYPE_MAIN = 2
```

I want to convert that to a string Type_Main

```
String a = someMagicalMethod(TYPE_MAIN);
System.out.println(a);
```

Such that the output would be

```
TYPE_MAIN
```

I can't use `Integer.toString(TYPE_MAIN)` because that would return the value of it which is `2`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you cannot inspect values of variables by using their name, that info is not available at run time, not even through reflection. Use a `Map<String, Integer>` to solve your problem:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("TYPE_MAIN", 2);
//...
String a = map.get("TYPE_MAIN").toString(); //someMagicalMethod(TYPE_MAIN);
System.out.println(a); //prints 2
```

Comment: I'm using that method right now but I want to optimize my code, and converting the representations to strings would help me do that. If I can't do it I'll use this method, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an Enum, then you can use String a = TYPE_MAIN.getName();