# Is there a way to get name of an array in java?

Tags: java

```
String[] names = {"abc"};
```

for this array can we retrieve the array's name `names` ?

We can get the class of the array, but can we get the name of the array?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The 'name' belongs to the local or instance variable, not the array.

Comment: A key part of understanding Java is learning the difference between an object, and the references to it.  Only references have names; the object itself has no name.

Comment: How would you reference it to get the name, if not by name?

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no."  The long answer is "nooooooooooo."  Absolutely no way, if it's a local variable.

Comment: What if you have two array variables, arrayA and arrayB, and both reference the *same array object* -- what would you say the "name" of the array object is? It doesn't make sense since (as @MarkPeters aptly puts), objects don't have "names".

Comment: Arrays don't have names.  Your variable `names` is a *reference* to an array, and there is no way to get that either.

Comment: Objects can have names if you make a custom object with an attribute called "name" :D.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule no, it's not possible. However, there are some circumstances when you can obtain the name of a variable through reflection:

1. When the variable is a field of a class - see [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) and
2. When the variable is a parameter of a method - see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: If the class file has been obfuscated, the name of the variable is likely to be non informative.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve similar functionality by creating your own class with a attribute called "name". The simplest example:

```java
MyArray myArray = new MyArray();


class MyArray{
    public String name = "myArray";
    public String[] names = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
}
```

If you wanted to have a different name for each instance make a constructor that accepts a name as an input parameter:

```java
MyArray myArray = new MyArray("myCustomName");

class MyArray{
    public String name = "myArray";
    public String[] names = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};

    public MyArray(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```