# Java get object variable name and get inner object variable name

Tags: java, android

We are using below code for getting variable name

```
public void printFieldNames(Object obj, Foo... foos) {
List<Foo> fooList = Arrays.asList(foos);
for(Field field : obj.getClass().getFields()) {
     if(fooList.contains(field.get()) {
          System.out.println(field.getName());
     }
  }
}
```

[from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

But some object contains another object for example

```
class A{
 String a="nil";
 B b;
}
class B{
int n1=0;
}
```

How to get object b varable details?

How to get custom list class name and object?

We need to get any object details assuming we don't know class name and inner object name

Answer (score 1):

I have completed the code by adding some constructors, but other than that it should be the same.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TestMain {

    public class A {
        public String a = "nil";
        public B b;

        public A(String a, B b) {
            super();
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public class B {
        public int n1 = 0;

        public B(int n1) {
            super();
            this.n1 = n1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        TestMain test = new TestMain();
        B b = test.new B(10);
        A a = test.new A("Test", b);
        for (Field field : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String name = field.getName();
            Object value = field.get(a);
            if (value instanceof B) {
                B bV = (B) value;
                for (Field fieldB : bV.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    fieldB.setAccessible(true);
                    String name1 = fieldB.getName();
                    Object value1 = fieldB.get(b);
                    System.out.printf("Field name: %s, Field value: %s%n", name1, value1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are trying to get all varable name and inner object name with out knowing any class name

Comment: The only use-case that I can think of, about what you describe is serialization and you have libraries for that.

Comment: We need to get any object details assuming we don't know class name and inner object name