# Compare name of String and name of Array int[]

Tags: java

I have one matrix which has two rows and one column. Each row has specific name such as `row0` and `row1`. I added some numbers in each row and column of this matrix. For example I have String `index` which can get one of the name of rows (`row0` or `row1`). How can I check if `index == "row0"` then print `row0[1]` and if `index == "row1"` then print `row1[1]`??

```
int[][] s = new int[2][3];
s[0][0] = 5;
s[0][1] = 10;
s[0][2] = 15;
s[0][1] = 25;
s[1][1] = 30;
s[2][1] = 45;
int[] row0 = new int[]{s[0][0], s[0][1], s[0][2]};
int[] row1 = new int[]{s[0][1], s[1][1], s[2][1]};
String index = "row0";
// if index= row0
System.out.println(row0[1]);
// if index=row1
System.out.println(row1[1]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Shouldn't you try to compare to the value in row0[1]? Like this: int index = 10; if (row0[1] == index) { //do somthing };

Comment: I mentioned clearly .

Comment: If you compare two values you need to use '==' instead of '=', maybe this is your error?

Comment: I have String " index" and different array "row0 and row1" so I want to check if string was equal to row0 then print one of its value or if index was equal to row1 then print on of the value of row1

Comment: I think you did not get my question

Comment: You could do something like this: `if (index.equals("row0") { System.out.println(row0[1]) }`. You are comparing `String`s, which are objects and not primitives, so use the `equals` method.

Comment: It is good idea but I want to make a code which can find it automatically

Comment: Is it possible ?

Comment: If you explain clearly what you are trying to do, then someone might be able to help you out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: now I have two int[] (row0 and row1) , so imagine that I made a code which can assign one of these name randomly as string item in index, so I want o check automatically if the name of String index is equal to name of first in[] row0 then print on of the its number which I already added and vise versa

Comment: @Ashkan Please consider up-voting and selecting my answer as the accepted solution, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your example there is probably something wrong:

```
int[][] s = new int[2][3]; // two rows, three cols
s[0][0] = 5;
s[0][1] = 10;
s[0][2] = 15;
s[0][1] = 25;
s[1][1] = 30;
s[2][1] = 45; // <---- 2 is out of bounds
int[] row0 = new int[]{s[0][0], s[0][1], s[0][2]};
int[] row1 = new int[]{s[0][1], s[1][1], s[2][1]};
```

Anyway, you could use a Map for your matrix and then address the rows with a String:

```
// ...code for s here..

Map<String, Integer[]> matrix = new HashMap<String, Integer[]>();
matrix.put("row0", new Integer[] {s[0][0], s[0][1], s[0][2]});
matrix.put("row1", new Integer[] {s[0][1], s[1][1], s[2][1]});
String index = "row0";
// if index= row0
System.out.println(matrix.get(index)[1]); // row0[1]
// if index=row1
index = "row1";
System.out.println(matrix.get(index)[1]); // row0[1]
```

Comment: More efficient to use a `Map()`, than my own answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can not check the equality of String objects with the `==` operator.
You have to use `.equals()` instead. This question has been asked many times in StackOverflow and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520464/8075923), explains it concisely.

What you want to do, is something like this:

```
final String ARRAY_NAME1 = "row0";
final String ARRAY_NAME2 = "row1";
String index = "row0";

if(index.equals(ARRAY_NAME1))
  System.out.print(row0[1]);
else if((index.equals(ARRAY_NAME2))
  System.out.print(row1[1]);
```

We got that out of the way.

Now, you say that you don't want to hardcode this and I absolutely understand.

So, if I were in your position, I would create a new class for this. It's really simple and easy to do, even for a total beginner.

```
//class can be named anything. (As long as it is meaningful)
public class IntegerArrayIdentity{

 /*This class will have two variables.
  A name, for comparison operations and
  the integer array that it will represent.*/
  public String name;
  public int[] array;

 /*Simple constructor. Takes the name and array as its parameters.
  You can change it to only take a name as a parameter, in case
  that you want to initialise the array later. Add new methods as you like*/
  public IntegerArrayIdentity(String name, int[] array){
    this.name = name;
    this.array = array;
  }
}
```

Then in your code, you can do:

```
int[] row0 = {8, 3, 5, 143, 27, 0};
IntegerArrayIdentity row0id = new IntegerArrayIdentity("row0", row0); 

if(index.equals(row0id.name))
  System.out.println(row0id.array[1]);



output -> '3'
```

All the above is just an example. You can implement it however you like.

Hope it helped.