# Java 9+ unable to get annotations of local variables of method

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Since Java 9, the way retention works for annotations which have as a target LOCAL_VARIABLE  has changed.  [Now the bytecode representation will hold information about annotated local variables in each method.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.2) Also, the specification states that `If m has an element whose value is java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME, the reflection libraries of the Java SE Platform must make a available at run time.`, which, if I understand correctly, confirms that at least the annotations on the local variables of the method should be available through reflection.

However, I have been trying to use reflection to find the annotations (or local variables annotated, or their values) with no luck.

Therefore, does anyone have a clue on how to do this or if it is possible? I am using java 11.

As an example, this is my Main class where I try to get the `@Parallel` annotations from the test method.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Main.class.getDeclaredMethod(\"test\").getAnnotations().length = " +
                Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("test").getAnnotations().length);

        System.out.println("Main.class.getDeclaredMethod(\"test\").getDeclaredAnnotations().length = " +
                Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("test").getDeclaredAnnotations().length);

        Annotation annotation = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("test").getAnnotation(Parallel.class);
        System.out.println("annotation = " + annotation);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void test() {
    @Parallel int a = 2;

    @Parallel int b = 4;
}
}
```

And this is my annotation implementation. I've just added everything as a target since I am only testing it:

```
@Target({ ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER,
    ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.PACKAGE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Parallel {
}
```

Running `javap -l -v -c -s Main.class` will show this:

```
void test();
descriptor: ()V
flags: (0x0000)
Code:
  stack=1, locals=3, args_size=1
     0: iconst_2
     1: istore_1
     2: iconst_4
     3: istore_2
     4: return
  LineNumberTable:
    line 22: 0
    line 24: 2
    line 25: 4
  RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations:
    0: #27(): LOCAL_VARIABLE, {start_pc=2, length=3, index=1}
      Parallel
    1: #27(): LOCAL_VARIABLE, {start_pc=4, length=1, index=2}
      Parallel
```

It's clear that information about the annotations on the local variables is there, I just don't know if reflection is able retrieve it (or if there's any other way to get it at runtime)

Comment: As far as I understand it, you cannot reflectively access local variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Reflection: How to get the name of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)

Comment: I am not necessarily interested in finding the name of the local variables or their values using reflection. I want to get the annotations on the local variables of a method.

Comment: if you really need to get annotations like that, you could try to use some bytecode processing libraries, like Javassist or more low level ASM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I have managed to get the annotations and bytecode information about them using the low level bytecode processing library ASM.

Answer (score 2):

A `.class` file contains more information than is exposed via reflection, but reflection does not expose information about local variables within a method.

I haven't found where this is formally stated, but can point to the Javadoc for [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) which has no methods exposing anything about local variables. Looking at the rest of the [the reflection package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), there's nothing else would that would be a better fit than `Method`.

Comment: However, from what I understand in the documentation: `If m has an element whose value is java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME, the reflection libraries of the Java SE Platform must make a available at run time.`  is that the annotations should be available. Please correct me if I am mistaken

Comment: @FlorinBlanaru From [§9.6.4.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.2): "_If `m` [the meta-annotation `Retention`] has an element whose value is `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`, the reflection libraries of the Java SE Platform must make `a` [the annotation] available at run time_". All it says is that the **reflection libraries** must make the annotation available at run time; if one cannot access local variables via reflection then local variables are exempt from the requirement.