Can a method access the caller's local variable?
I'd like my output to use singular nouns, when the reported quantity is one. Currently I keep doing things like:
logger.debug("Got {} row{}", rows, rows == 1 ? "" : 's');

but that gets tedious.
So, I'm thinking of a method, that would return the entire string "1 row" or "5 rows" depending on the value. The static String printable(int value, String name) is trivial to do, but tedious to use, it'd be invoked as printable(rows, "row"), which is redundant to anyone reading the code.
Perhaps, Java can do with just one argument? One of the:

printable(rows) -- with the invoked method looking up the name of the variable passed to it in order to construct the noun (singular or plural depending on the value).
printable("rows") -- with the invoked method looking up the value of the variable in the caller's scope (by the specified name)?

Something like this can be done with C preprocessor at compile-time, for example:
#define PRINTABLE(val) printable(val, #val)

Can Java do it (at runtime)?
Would be nice, if all of these could be skipped, if the current log-level is not verbose enough to actually output the log-entry anyway.

There are a lot of problems with this, like coupling program behavior to variable names, or printing boxs instead of boxes.

Plurality rules are complex in english, let alone i18ned. the expression you pass can be 15 pages long, it doesn't have to be a simple name. And even if it is, that information is deleted by the compiler (unless you include debug symbols. You do not want to resort to trying to grab those in log behaviour). Who are you logging for? Programmers? Just ditch plurals then. They don't need them to understand what is happening. Java does not have a preprocessor like that. A lombok plugin could do it, in theory.

Maybe just create a List of name value pairs, where the value for the key is the plural value. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

not to speak of printable(x+y)  --  the virtual machine does not know the names of local variables, just an index is used - you would need some kind of pre-compiler for that (or maybe using annotations)

printable(rows, "row") For most purposes this is the way to go. In a previous workplace of mine we had a class with several utility methods in this style, including an overloaded version where the caller could specify the singular and the plural form separately. It worked well for us.

As previous commenters said, there is no automatism for building the singular or plural form out of a variable name. What about child or count? Besides that, who cares about the singular or plural form in debug output? Just log "row = " + row . You want to have the exact variable name in debug output, especially as it is perfectly possible that both variables, row and rows exist in that method.

"Can Java do it (at runtime)?"
No,
You can try to setup preprocessor, but it looks like overkill.
Maybe this?
logger.debug("Got {}", formatRows(rows));


That'd only work for "rows", whereas I'd like a generic method for all (most) nouns -- columns, fields, cats...

@MikhailT. Sorry ... you can't do that.  A method (like printRows) cannot determine the name of the caller's variable.  It sees the value of the rows variable not its name.

This is currently the only answer that addresses the meat of the question: can you access the name of the variable being passed to this function? No.

@MikhailT. you have actually two question in your question. How to access variable and how to pluralize string. Since answer for fist one is "it is impossible"? second one doesn't make any sense, so I offer solution to your as best as it is possible in this circumstances. You need to create new question with realistic goal.

You could do something like:
public static String plural( int n ) {
   return n == 1 ? "" ? "s";
}

You also might be able to make your debug method something like this if this is very common:
public static void dbug( String msg, int val )
   log.debug( msg, val, plural( val ));
}

As talex points out this can get messy with a lot of corner cases.

Maybe this:
public String formatValue(String singular, String plural, int value) {
    return String.format("%d", value) + " " + value == 1 ? singular : plural;
}

or even better:
public String formatValue(String singular, String plural, String format, int value) {
    return String.format(format, value) + " " + value == 1 ? singular : plural;
}


Missing some brackets I think.
First method is OK, but second method will throw Exceptions if the wrong format is passed.

Yes, these are easy -- but I don't want to have to pass the plural and singular strings. I want them both derived from the name of variable with value.

You might want that, but it's not possible.

@Mikhail T.:  Here's a five minute life lesson.

There are definitely brackets missing. Besides that, there is no advantage of String.format("%d", value) + " " + (value == 1 ? singular : plural) over the simpler value + " " + (value == 1 ? singular : plural). The latter is also more efficient.
